# State Based fontFamily in Android

Tags: android, xml, font-family, statelistdrawable

StateListDrawables and  are great for setting different drawables for each state of a view, but is there a way to tie in what text style that view should use for each of those states?

For example, if you had a button that was fontFamily of "sans-serif-medium", and when focused, the button **fontFamily** became "sans-serif-light". I can imagine how I would do this with code, but is there a way to do it with XML similar to the  used for drawables?